# Recommended workflow for keeping git branch up to date

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have two goals, and I need a workflow to achieve them while working on my features (master is an enterprise github repo).

Goals:

- Keep my branch up to date
- Be able to see changes I made using `git diff` and `git show`

I am new to github, but I tried few scenarios to achieve this and they don't help me.

Initially, I create a new branch (tracks origin/master) and I make a code change.

I commit the change and use `git push origin` to publish this change to github.

Then I create a PR and let people comment.

I get good feedback, I make code changes and commit on top of my 1st commit.

What to do to keep my branch in sync with origin/master?

I tried updating my local branch by merging via `git pull`. It goes ok, but now if I do `git show` I won't see my changes, I will see latest master commit.

I tried updating my local branch by rebasing via `git pull --rebase`. I can use `git show` to see my changes, but my local and remote branches are out of sync, and I have to use `git push origin -f` to update my github PR with second change.

I am open for suggestions, thank you!

Comment: Everything you mentioned sounds correct.  If your only ask is how to view a diff of a file from one commit to another, might I recommend that you get a Git plugin for your IDE?  IntelliJ, for example, does a great job of letting you diff a file against any commit in the same branch, or even against other branches.  Much nicer than the command line.

Comment: Did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is correct approach. There is a big difference between `pull` and `pull --rebase`. It will do `git fetch && git merge origin/master` resp. `git fetch && git rebase origin/master`. Both of them are correct approach. The difference is in the tree history and in most cases it's company policy what to rather use.

With rebase you will always change history and will need to force push. With merge, you will not change history, but last commit is the merge.

Do not expect that you will have only one commit which will be pushed, so the diff should not be only for one commit but for whole branch. If you only need to see the diff, you can run:

```
git show HEAD~1
```

or
    git show HEAD~4..HEAD~1

to see all changes in last few commits except of the last one (merge).

Or you can try something like this

```
git diff --boundary HEAD~1..origin/master
```

P.S.: rebase and force push can be pretty dangerous when more people are working on the same branch. Force push only when you are sure that you are the only one working on the branch.

There can be some problems with the comments as well. Not sure how Github, but Gitlab will not show comments for completely changed or removed lines after force push.